# Flash as3 buttons and pages link

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am new to flash as3 and want to create full website on flash. The problem I am facing is that I have 3 buttons and 3 pages in same .fla frames and I want these buttons to open relevant page with fade in & fade out transitions and when page1 is open button1 will not work again upon clicking. I shall be thankful if anyone can help me in this regard. Or if you have any alternate to it let me know that.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right you want something like that:

button 1 goes to Page 1

button 2 goes to Page 2

button 3 goes to Page 3

Without thinking much i would create three movieclips and use the movieclips as pages. After that its only a matter of checking which button is pressed and add the relevant movieclip on the stage.
Let me know if you have any specific questions about that.

Comment: Exactly but with fade in and fade out transitions and also when page 1 is open button 1 again wont work when someone click on it. Hope you can help me in this matter.

Comment: For the fade in and fade out effects you can use the _alpha attribute and using a listener ENTER_FRAME you can create a function to raise the alpha. Regarding the button, if you want to disable it you can use  `button.mouseChildren = false` when one of the three pages/movieclips are on the stage or visible

Comment: I cant get your point. I shall be thankful if you could create one sample on this.

Comment: I would put the code for the alpha on each page `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
private function onEnter(e:Event):void
{
    page1.alpha=page1.alpha+increaseRate;
}`


And the code for the button on stage
`addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
private function onEnter(e:Event):void
{ if (page1.enable){
button1.enable=true;
   } 
}`

Let me know if that helps. If you have any questions dont forget to mention the part you are having trouble with.

Comment: I could not understand your point :( As I said I am new to As3 and dont know how to work on it. Can you make a sample .fla for me as per my requirement. Just simple buttons and pages. Thank you for your help.

Comment: First of all, i would really like to help you but you must understand that some effort from your side is also required in order to understand the basic principles of as3. I can't help you if you haven't even been through a basic research. 
There are many people who have done great tutorials for beginners and the only thing that require from you is 10 seconds to search for them.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKvUjjQT2Dc (button and aplha example)http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-nh_zwuEkY(basic hello world tutorial)

Comment: Once you have your basic code structure you can post it here and discuss ur problems